# How to get php var with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a html div (with id `example`) where i want to print php variable `$test`.
My php looks like this:

```
<?php 

function Test(){
//some action;
return 'Hello World!';
}

$test = Test();
echo $test;

?>
```

Also i have javascript file :

```
$.get( "ajax/index.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#example" ).html( data );
});
```

What's the problem ?

My html file :

```
...
<script>
function Ajax(){
    $.get( "../Auth/user_save.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#example" ).html( data );});
</script>
<div id = "example"></div>
<input type='submit' onClick='Ajax();'></input>
```

Comment: `$test` has no value in function.

Comment: using the `console.log(data)`, check what actually return from the page.

Comment: What are you seeing?

Comment: what is inside of index.html ? you should be sending request  to appropriate php file that has function `Test`  in it. are you using url rewrite? otherwise you have to send request to `ajax/{YOUR_FILE}.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript has `html` link, but you are trying to call `php` file:

```
$.get( "ajax/index.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#example" ).html( data );
});
```

Change it to

```
$.get( "ajax/your_php_file.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#example" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: Changed, page just refreshed.

Comment: Have you specified the correct path here : `ajax/your_php_file.php`?

Comment: yes my path is correct, just nothing happends.I expect a text in my div.

Comment: Can you update your question with your php file and html file? Also check for the error in browser console.

Comment: Updated the html part

Comment: OMG, i swear i didnt change anything but now it works.I think it was problem with server update data delay.Thanks in advance to all of u.

Comment: @U.Alex Welcome. Sometimes, we need a force refresh in our browser.